# Iterate over array and create collections of items in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, collections

I have a huge array, which I loop with a foreach.

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $sender = $item->getSender();
    $id = $item->getId();
}
```

The $sender can be any string but different items ($item) can have the same string. That means in one foreach the $sender can have the same value. Now I want to store the ids ($id) in an array or something similiar for each $sender. So if $sender was "abcde" 3 times I want an array with 3 items and lets say $sender was "ztra" 2 times, I want to have an array with 2 ids for that as well.

So what I need is a collection of ids per sender, how could I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$perSender = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $perSender[$item->getSender()][] = $item->getId();
}

var_dump($perSender);
```

should do the trick....

Answer (score 0):

if you store an array within each array, then you can have a collection of anything you want per item.

In the case of multiple IDs, this is as easy as:

```
$items = array(
   array( 'id' => array(1,2,3,4), 'otherStuff'=>'xyz' ),
   array( 'id' => array(5,6,7,8), 'otherStuff'=>'abc' ),
);
```